# Excel cannot release read only when opened through harmon.ie

Tags: excel, sharepoint-online, harmon.ie

When opening a .xlsm file with harmon.ie (v 5.3.0.9183) from SharePoint Online, a pop up showing eventID: 300 - "We're having trouble connecting to the server. If this keeps happening, contact your help desk." is thrown and the document remains stuck in "Read Only".

Opening the file directly from the online library through a browser (Chrome, IE11 tested) does not encounter the issue.

Nothing appearing in the Event log except the application 300 above.
Events logged in the framework and harmonie .log files are:

harmonie.log - OCSAwarenessFactory - Failed to find ContactWrapper for sip

framework.log - !MESSAGE Failed to find ContactWrapper for sip

Any guidance on additional troubleshooting would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

These message from the logs are not related to the issue. You are running a too old version. You must upgrade to our latest 6.8 version from our web site. If you are customer submit a request to support@harmon.ie (only for customers0

----- Jean